# dotnet build not working inside the container

Tags: docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2022

Since container is not building with the full project I commented docker file as bellow . then I executed manually dotnet build command inside container. it failed like below. But when I build the container from outside from the visual studio it is building fine.

```
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  myapp -> /app/build/myapp.dll
  myapp -> /app/build/myapp.Views.dll
  /bin/sh: 2: /tmp/tmped91456469694a38bc5ed8e7d4b423b1.exec.cmd: docker: not found
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/1.11.1/build/Container.targets(97,5): error : Docker is not installed or is not in the current PATH. [/src/myapp/myapp.csproj]

Build FAILED.

/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/1.11.1/build/Container.targets(97,5): error : Docker is not installed or is not in the current PATH. [/src/myapp/myapp.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Here is the my Dockerfile

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs

COPY ["myapp/myapp.csproj", "myapp/"]
COPY ["myapp/NuGet.Config", "myapp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "myapp/myapp.csproj" --configfile myapp/NuGet.Config
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/myapp"
#RUN dotnet build "myapp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

#FROM build AS publish
#RUN dotnet publish "myapp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

#FROM base AS final
#WORKDIR /app
#COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
#ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Comment: You try to access docker from within a docker container?

Comment: yes I tried. But command not working. I think it is not suppose to work inside the container. as i mentioned I have there is a another container build with same dockerfile from the outside of VS. dotnet build command is working fine on that container and docker command not working in there also.

Comment: Off-topic, but .NET 5 is already eol since 08 May 2022

Comment: @Nwn - I deleted my previous answer. What is in your NuGet config file? (Remove any personal nuget repo details before updating your question). I'm wondering if it's not restoring everything needed to build the app.